# Escaping Fields Array in CakePHP

Tags: php, security, cakephp, model

I currently have:

```
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
        array(
            'fields' => array(
                "CASE
                    WHEN
                        Application.program_type_id = 3
                        AND Application.program_type_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN {$keys['program_type_id_program_type_id']}
                        ELSE 0
                END as program_type_score,
                CASE
                    WHEN
                        Application.priority_subject_area_id = 1
                        AND Application.priority_subject_area_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN {$keys['priority_subject_area_id_priority_subject_area_id']}
                        ELSE 0
                END as priority_subject_area_priority_subject_area_score,
                User.*"
            ),
            'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this),
            'alias' => 'User',
            'limit' => null,
            'offset' => null,
            'joins' => $joins,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Application.state' => 'accepted',
                'Role.role' => 'mentor'
            ),
            'order' => null,
            'group' => null
        ),
        $this->User
    );
```

I need to change the case statements from this:

```
CASE
                        WHEN
                            Application.program_type_id = 3
                            AND Application.program_type_id IS NOT NULL
                            THEN {$keys['program_type_id_program_type_id']}
                            ELSE 0
                    END as program_type_score
```

to this:

```
CASE
                        WHEN
                            Application.program_type_id = $user['User']['value']
                            AND Application.program_type_id IS NOT NULL
                            THEN {$keys['program_type_id_program_type_id']}
                            ELSE 0
                    END as program_type_score
```

How do I escape `$user['User']['value']`? Would Sanitize::escape() work, however, it is already deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I use the single quotes in php so the way I would do this would be:

```
'CASE
                    WHEN
                        Application.program_type_id = '.$user['User']['value'].'
                        AND Application.program_type_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN {$keys['program_type_id_program_type_id']'}
                        ELSE 0
                END as program_type_score'
enter code here
```

and you should be done.

One of the reasons I prefer the single quotes. sometimes a itsybitsy more work, but usualy no worry about escaping things. Atleast als long you don't mix HTML with Javascript using PHP variables. Then it gets always messy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think you got my question. My problem escaping like mysql_real_escape_string() functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CakePHP does the escaping by itself on the `find()` method, as the docs say: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#sql-escaping